# SQL using like to search word in a shorter where expression?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, sql-like

While practicing ORACLE SQL query, i stumbled upon a simple question of returning records with name containing a certain word like 'Jackson'.

I used a where clause :

```
    where NAME like 'Jackson %' and NAME like '% Jackson %';
```

Is there a simpler or shorter way to do this?

Sorry for the confusing title and this noob question. Feel free to change. Thank you.

RECORD:

- Micheal Jackson
- Jackson Jack
- Mojo Smith-Jackson Jill
- Milo Jackson Chen

RESULTS:

- Micheal Jackson
- Jackson Jack
- Milo Jackson Chen

Comment: You just need `'%Jackson%'` to find Jackson anywhere in the string.

Comment: I am not looking for 'Jackson' just as a string. I'm looking for it as a WORD. Sorry.

Comment: Please specify the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as:

```
where NAME like '%Jackson %'
```

The `%` wildcard can match no characters at all.

If you want to find the word "Jackson" anywhere in the string (so it doesn't match, say, "Smith-Jackson"), then do:

```
where ' '||NAME||' ' like '% Jackson %'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Never thought concatenation was allowed like that.